# Creating bar code labels with ColdFusion and JavaScript DYMO SDK

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am trying to use the DYMO SDK to print bar codes to labels for packages.  I want to be able to create the bar code objects without using the DYMO software.  I am writing this code in ColdFusion.  Right now I have some code to generate the bar code into HTML and display it on the webpage.  However, when I print the label using JavaScript from the DYMO SDK it prints the bar code incorrectly, the value of the barcode is just "unknown".  Anyway, hopefully someone has some experience using this library.  Here is the JavaScript that I am using to print the label:

```
// prints the label
printButton.onclick = function () {
    try {
        // open label
        var labelXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">\
<PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>\
<Id>Address</Id>\
<PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName>\
<DrawCommands/>\
<ObjectInfo>\
<BarcodeObject>\
<Name>Barcode</Name>\
<ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" />\
<BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" />\
<LinkedObjectName>BarcodeText</LinkedObjectName>\
<Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation>\
<IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored>\
<IsVariable>True</IsVariable>\
<Text>BARCODE</Text>\
<Type>Code39</Type>\
<Size>Medium</Size>\
<TextPosition>Bottom</TextPosition>\
<TextFont Family="Arial" Size="8" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
<CheckSumFont Family="Arial" Size="8" Bold="False" Italic="False" Underline="False" Strikeout="False" />\
<TextEmbedding>None</TextEmbedding>\
<ECLevel>0</ECLevel>\
<HorizontalAlignment>Center</HorizontalAlignment>\
<QuietZonesPadding Left="0" Top="0" Right="0" Bottom="0" />\
</BarcodeObject>\
<Bounds X="332" Y="150" Width="4455" Height="1260" />\
</ObjectInfo>\
</DieCutLabel>';
        var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);

        // set label text
        label.setObjectText("Barcode", textTextArea.value);
```

This is the code that I am using to generate the barcode:

```
<cfoutput>
<!---span style="#Attributes.TextFontTop#">#Attributes.TextTop#</span--->
<div>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#len(Attributes.InputValue)#"> 
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],1,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: black; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],6,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: white; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],2,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: black; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],7,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: white; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],3,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: black; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],8,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: white; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],4,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: black; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],9,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: white; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:#val(mid(code39[asc(mid(Attributes.InputValue,i,1))],5,1)*(Attributes.BarWidth)+(Attributes.BarWidth/2))#px solid; border-color: black; height: #Attributes.BarHeight#px;margin-bottom:#Attributes.MarginBottom#px;margin-top:#Attributes.MarginTop#px;"></span>
    <span style="border-right:2px solid; border-color: white; height: 50px;margin-bottom:2px;margin-top:2px;"></span>   <!--- space between individual codes --->
</cfloop>
</div>
<span style="#Attributes.TextFontBottom#">#Attributes.TextBottom#</span>
```

And this is the test HTML that I am using to display it:

```
<div id="textTextArea">
   <CF_barcode39 InputValue="ABCDEFGHIJ" BarWidth="2" BarHeight="50"                                         TextTop="BarWidth=2 BarHeight=50" TextBottom="ABCDEFGHIJ">
</div>
```

Comment: Last time I printed barcodes, it was just a matter of choosing the correct barcode font.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, there isn't extensive documentation regarding the DYMO SDK which was making it difficult for me to understand the XML strings that I am using to make the different label objects.  I am able to render a view of the label preview in the browser now with the bar code and I'm pretty sure that I don't need to use coldfusion to generate the bar codes.  The dymo sdk does it for me if I make the xml string correctly.  Unfortunately I am now having issues printing so I can't check for sure.

Answer (score 1):

My server generates Barcodes for production of admission tickets.  I highly recommend http://cfbarbecue.riaforge.org/.  Follow the directions on the install.txt file, but basically, you copy some files to your lib folder under your ColdFusion directory.  Here is a sample of code I use to generate the barcode.

```
<cfset bbq = createObject("component", "CFBarbecue").init() />
<cfset barcode = bbq.createImage( type="#var.barcodetype#", data="#session.cart.checkOut[i].BARCODE#", checkDigit=false, barWidth="1", barHeight="30", drawLabel="FALSE") />
```

It's been a while since I have installed it, but I don't think you need to do any mappings.